# XAML Update UI INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, inotifypropertychanged

Background:

I have an application that has list of `CheckBox`es and `Button`.
If the user selects a (or multiple) CheckBox and Click on the button, the Button event handler checks which CheckBox is checked. Based on that, it runs a process (ie. gpupate).

Then, I have an image (`Visibility = "hidden"`) next to CheckBox in XAML. After the button is clicked, the code behind sets it to Visibility.Visible.

After the process is done, the Source of the image is changed to a different image. Bascically, the first image shows the process is running, second image is a check showing its completed.

I am trying to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface, so the UI is updated automatically after I change the visibility. Sometimes, UI is not updated after the the visibility is changed because there are number of CheckBoxes.

However, since I am not using any property, I cannot really bind it to something (or may be I am missing something) and INPC interface.

How can I implement the interface (or similar functionality).

XAML Code

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image x:Name="oneImage" 
           Source="{StaticResource inProcessImage}"
           Visibility="Hidden" />

    <CheckBox x:Name="oneCheckBox"
               Content="CheckBox"
               Style="{StaticResource normalCheckBox}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code Behind inside Button Event Handler

```
if (oneCheckBox.IsChecked ?? false)
{
    oneImage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //run GPUpdate
    });
    deleteHistoryImage.Source = (ImageSource)Resources["doneCheckImage"];
}
```

I do not have anything regarding the implementation of interface because I do not know what do I need to bind `Visibility` modifier with.

Comment: You'll need a view model containing your properties that you'll bind to. The codebehind has nothing to do with that (except that it may hold an instance of the view model, although I prefer an implementation of the Singletone-pattern on that one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not what you're looking for, but it will update the GUI manually.

`public void UpdateUI()
{
   Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(delegate { }));
}`

call `UpdateUI();` after you change the visibility.

Comment: thanks, it did update the UI. will look in to singleton as @trade suggested.